# How can I put search function in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native but trying to make my app. I'm trying to implement a search filter function but I'm not sure how to do it...
getData function and useEffect will display a list of stocks on the screen. so what I'm thinking is to add text input/search to only show certain lists, but have no idea how to do it.

```
const getData = async(setStoreKey, setName, setIsLoading) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if(user !== null){
        const email = user.email;
        const UserInfo = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', email));
        if(UserInfo.exists()){
            setStoreKey(UserInfo.data().storeKey)
            setName(UserInfo.data().name);
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    else{
        console.log('None')
    }
    return
}
}

const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")

    const updateSearch = (search) => {
        setSearch(search);
        console.log(id)
        const filtered = coffeeStock.filter( id => {
        return id.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        })
    }

    const [storeKey, setStoreKey] = useState([]);
    const [userName, setName] = useState([]);
    const [coffeeStock, setCoffeeStock] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        getData(setStoreKey, setName, setIsLoading);
    }, [storeKey, isLoading])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isLoading === false){
        const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'Store', storeKey, 'coffeeDB'), (snapshot) => {
        setCoffeeStock(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>  (
            
            {
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
            number: doc.data(),
            }
        )));
    });
    return unsub;
    }
    }, [isLoading]);


const Order = (id, number) => {
    navigation.navigate('Order', {
        id, 
        number,
    });
};


return (
    <View>
        <SearchBar placeholder='Type Coffee'  onChangeText={updateSearch} value={search}/>
        {coffeeStock.map(({id, data: { number }}) => (

        <CustomListItem key={id} id={id} number={number} Order={Order}  />
        ))}
    </View>
)
}
```

this is customList.js

```
const CustomListItem = ({id, number, Order}) => {
console.log('vv',number);
const user = auth.currentUser;
const name = user.displayName;

return (
    <ListItem key={id} bottomDivider onPress={() => {Order({id, number})}} >
        <Avatar rounded source={require('../assets/icon.png')} />
        <ListItem.Content >
            <ListItem.Title style={{ fontWeight: '800'}}>{id}</ListItem.Title>
            <ListItem.Subtitle numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
                Stock: {number}
            </ListItem.Subtitle>
        </ListItem.Content>
        
    </ListItem>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [React Native Search Filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-search-filter) package to achieve your goal easily.